# Way to get VS 2008 to stop forcing indentation on namespaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style, namespaces, indentation

I've never really been a big fan of the way most editors handle namespaces. They always force you to add an extra *pointless* level of indentation.

For instance, I have a lot of code in a page that I would much rather prefer formatted as

```
namespace mycode{

class myclass{
  void function(){
    foo();
  }
  void foo(){
    bar();
  }
  void bar(){
    //code..
  }

}

}
```

and not something like

```
namespace mycode{

  class myclass{
    void function(){
      foo();
    }
    void foo(){
      bar();
    }
    void bar(){
      //code..
    }

  }

}
```

Honestly, I don't really even like the class thing being indented most of the time because I usually only have 1 class per file. And it doesn't look as bad here, but when you get a ton of code and lot of scopes, you can easily have indentation that forces you off the screen, and plus here I just used 2-space tabs and not 4-space as is used by us.

Anyway, **is there some way to get Visual Studio to stop trying to indent namespaces for me like that?**

Comment: I think you can avoid this with ReSharper, a quite expensive solution to what should be a trivial problem though. :)

Comment: yuck, Java-style formatting ;)

Comment: I don't get it.. I don't know Java lol. if your talking about `void bar(){` all on one line, then that's just how I naturally write code since I learned C.. but VS kindly changes it to `void bar()\n{` for me..

Comment: Hey, I didn't see this question when I opened mine, but I noticed it now in the "Related" list. I put up a 500 bounty on it and received a great answer; since mine contains better answers I'll also vote to close this as a duplicate, even if it was asked earlier. My question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727862/is-there-any-way-to-make-visual-studio-stop-indenting-namespaces/3782433#3782433

Comment: @Skurmedel: I have ReSharper and I don't see this facility. If you can provide more specific information I'd be grateful.

Comment: @RenniePet: It was ages since I used ReSharper but either they removed the facility or I abused one of the settings. Sorry I can't recall better, but I remember you could control the indentations for pretty much everything.

Comment: Anyone who's interested in this (and it has been viewed over 700 times) please vote here to try to get Microsoft to provide this option:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6367724-add-option-to-prevent-indentation-of-classes-insid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a hack, but here goes:

```
namespace mycode{ 
#if 0
}
#endif

class myclass{
    ...
```

Comment: I should've added "without really bad hacks" to my question :)

Comment: This works with Visual Studio 2012, but not with Visual Studio 2015. With VS 2015 it considers "#if 0" to be a syntax error. Changing to "#if false" fixes that, but the editor no longer lets itself be fooled so you're back to the problem of the namespace contents being indented. Damn.