# Is there any way to make Visual Studio stop indenting namespaces?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, namespaces, indentation

Visual Studio keeps trying to indent the code inside namespaces.

For example:

```
namespace Foo
{
   void Bar();

   void Bar()
   {

   }

}
```

Now, if I un-indent it manually then it stays that way. But unfortunately if I add something right before `void Bar();` - such as a comment - VS will keep trying to indent it.

This is so annoying that basically because of this only reason I almost never use namespaces in C++. I can't understand why it tries to indent them (what's the point in indenting 1 or even 5 tabs *the whole file*?), or how to make it stop.

Is there a way to stop this behavior? A config option, an add-in, a registry setting, hell even a hack that modifies devenv.exe directly.

Comment: You could disable auto-indenting entirely. Or set it to indent by a smaller amount (say, 2 spaces instead of 1 tab)

Comment: This (non-configurable indentation settings) is one of many reasons I stopped editing files in Visual Studio years ago...  :)

Comment: I will award the bounty to whoever finds a solution that has no side effects, or as little side effects as possible. For now the best answer, IMO, is bacar's; if no better answers are provided I will award the answer to him.

Comment: That's why I'm using Eclipse CDT ;) It is possible to use VS compiler within Eclipse so it may be worth a try.

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3894937-option-to-stop-indenting-namespaces-in-c-code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a macro that could help you. It will remove indentation if it detects that you are currently creating a `namespace`. It is not perfect but seems to work so far.

```
Public Sub aftekeypress(ByVal key As String, ByVal sel As TextSelection, ByVal completion As Boolean) _
        Handles TextDocumentKeyPressEvents.AfterKeyPress
    If (Not completion And key = vbCr) Then
        'Only perform this if we are using smart indent
        If DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "C/C++").Item("IndentStyle").Value = 2 Then
            Dim textDocument As TextDocument = DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument")
            Dim startPoint As EditPoint = sel.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint()
            Dim matchPoint As EditPoint = sel.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint()
            Dim findOptions As Integer = vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchCase + vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchWholeWord + vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsBackwards
            If startPoint.FindPattern("namespace", findOptions, matchPoint) Then
                Dim lines = matchPoint.GetLines(matchPoint.Line, sel.ActivePoint.Line)
                ' Make sure we are still in the namespace {} but nothing has been typed
                If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(lines, "^[\s]*(namespace[\s\w]+)?[\s\{]+$") Then
                    sel.Unindent()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Since it is running all the time, you need to make sure you are installing the macro inside in your [`EnvironmentEvents` project item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b27f9kz(VS.71).aspx) inside MyMacros. You can only access this module in the Macro Explorer (Tools->Macros->Macro Explorer).

One note, it does not currently support "packed" namespaces such as

```
namespace A { namespace B {
...
}
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To support "packed" namespaces such as the example above and/or support comments after the namespace, such as `namespace A { /* Example */`, you can try to use the following line instead:

```
 If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(lines, "^[\s]*(namespace.+)?[\s\{]+$") Then
```

I haven't had the chance to test it a lot yet, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There was an error that I now corrected, but besides that it works perfectly. Grats on the bounty.

Comment: Works fine for typing but not for pasting or e.g. Visual Assist's "Create Implementation" functionality whereas bacar's solution does do the trick there. It is cleaner though.

Comment: The question might seems stupid, but I really cannot find an answer: where are we supposed to paste this macro ?

Answer (score 58):

As KindDragon points out, Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 has an option to stop indenting.

You can uncheck TOOLS -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Indentation -> Indent namespace contents.

Comment: It seems to have become broken again... At least in Update 4. I hope they fix it.

Comment: It's indeed broken. Though you can use clang format and simply work around the mess.

Comment: I just tried VS2013 Update 5 CTP; it appears to be working again. Hopefully it stays that way for the official Update 5 release.

Comment: This is the best answer. Works as I expected in VS 2015.

Comment: The question is for `C++`, but does anyone know if there is an option for `C#` in `visual-studio-2019`? I looked but cannot find an `Indent namespace contents` checkbox in the `Indentation` options.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> __Code Style__ -> Formatting -> Indentation -> Indent namespace contents.

Comment: Works perfectly. This should have been the accepted answer, much simpler than the macro solution that was accepted.

Answer (score 31):

Just don't insert anything before the first line of code. You could try the following approach to insert a null line of code (it seems to work in VS2005):

```
namespace foo
{; // !<---
void Test();
}
```

This seems to suppress the indentation, but compilers may issue warnings and code reviewers/maintainers may be surprised! (And quite rightly, in the usual case!)

Comment: I like this too. Seems like even a macro that expands to nothing is enough to suppress the indentation. So you can `#define SUPPRESS_INDENTATION` and then open the namespace like `namespace foo { SUPPRESS_INDENTATION` :)

Comment: Nice - the intent is somewhat clearer and the compiler is hopefully less likely to raise warnings :)

Comment: While this has been my favourite solution, I wanted to mention that this trick does not work in VS2013. There is a user configuration setting in VS2013 which prevents this from happening (when it works; see other answer).

Answer (score 15):

Probably not what you wanted to hear, but a lot of people work around this by using macros:

```
#define BEGIN_NAMESPACE(x) namespace x {
#define END_NAMESPACE }
```

Sounds dumb, but you'd be surprised how many system headers use this.  (glibc's stl implentation, for instance, has `_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE()` for this.)

I actually prefer this way, because I always tend to cringe when I see un-indented lines following a `{`.  That's just me though.

Comment: I think this is more for compatibility with old compilers than because of Visual Studio =)

Comment: @andreas I think that way you can change the namespace of the whole lib easily without editing all the source files

Answer (score 9):

You could also forward declare your types (or whatever) inside the namespace then implement outside like this:

```
namespace test {
    class MyClass;
}

class test::MyClass {
//...
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2017+

[image]
You can get to this "Indent namespace contents" setting under Tools->Options then Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->Indention. It's deep in the menus but extremely helpful once found.

Comment: please dont't leave just link only answers!

Comment: You could include the screenshot. Anyway, this is the only correct answer for VS2017+.

Answer (score 3):

I understand the problem when there are nested namespaces. I used to pack all the `namespace`s in a single line to avoid the multiple indentation. It will leave one level, but that's not as bad as many levels. It's been so long since I have used VS that I hardly remember those days.

```
namespace outer { namespace middle { namespace inner {
    void Test();
    .....
}}}
```