# Change Visual Studio 2010 indentation rules

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indentation

Is there a way to change VS2010 indentation rules for C++?

Basically I just want to remove the automatic indentation for the contents of a namespace.

From:

```
namespace name {
    //contents automatically indented
    class MyClass
    {
        //...
    };
}
```

to

```
namespace name {

//contents automatically indented
class MyClass
{
    //...
};

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a **macro** available, and judging from the positive feedback, it is working well. The code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727862/is-there-any-way-to-make-visual-studio-stop-indenting-namespaces).

Once installed the Macro can be accessed in the Macro Explorer (`Tools->Macros->Macro Explorer`). This is not available for the VS Express Editions.

Other basic Formatting Options are available under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C++ > Formatting`