# Namespace indentation in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, indentation

Visual Studio indents code within namespace. This can be avoided when disabling indentation globally, which is not what I want. In all other cases, the indentation is fine, I simply don't like the fact that all code is one level - this makes it look ugly to me.

```
namespace X
{
    public class A
    {}
}
```

I would prefer it like this:

```
namespace X
{
public class A
{

}
}
```

In C++, there's a nice workaround as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729649/1591992):

```
namespace X
{; // the ; after opening brace makes visual studio not indent the class below.

class A
{};

}
```

But in C#, a namespace cannot directly contain fields so this doesn't work.

How can I get Visual Studio to stop indenting namespaces without disabling indentation globally?

**Update** Visual Studio 2013 behavior C++ has changed

```
Tools->Options->C/C++->Formatting->Indentation: [ ] Indent namespace contents
```

enables my preferred formatting, while the {; trick doesn't work anymore. But no change for C# that I could find.

Comment: Select all code inside namespace braces and press `Shift + TAB`. Job done! :-)

Comment: That won't work when formatting the document.

Comment: I was only joking / being sarcastic! This seems like an odd question as I have NEVER worked anywhere that would accept this code format! Most modern monitors are wide-screen and really wouldn't make much difference with a leading tab or not!

Comment: I also wondered why one would want to do such a thing and have the code formatted in a way I've never seen before. Anyway, if there is a way and it makes @Wilbert happy so be it - I don't know any though :)

Comment: It's a personal preference, but I do not seem to be the only one with that preference. And yes, a solution to this would make me happy.

Comment: There's another thread about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225487/way-to-get-vs-2008-to-stop-forcing-indentation-on-namespaces

Comment: And yes, it's a personal preference, and I wish there was a good solution. What inspired me to want to do this is that I sometimes copy bits of code, for example a single method, from C# to Java/Android. The result needs to be edited of course, but not having to remove the extra indentation would be one less editing step.

Comment: Anyone who's interested in this (and it has been viewed over 500 times) please vote here to try to get Microsoft to provide this option:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6367724-add-option-to-prevent-indentation-of-classes-insid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Text Editor → c# → Tabs → Indenting — Set to "Block"
2. Text Editor → c# → Formatting → General — Turn off every checkbox saying "automatically format..."

Comment: Please say what the checkboxes are, instead of "first two". It would help in case VS changes its settings dialogs. And possibly remove Tabs in the second, it's misleading.

Answer (score 8):

This question deserves a new answer in 2021. C#10 (shipped with .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022) introduces [File Scoped Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/file-scoped-namespaces). It allows the following syntax:

```cs
namespace Hello.World;

class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

So, we can completely remove indentation added by the namespace declaration.
The old syntax is supported too.